# Java program that scan how many base number and the exponent value then display the sum of them

Tags: java

I want to make a java program using for loop that scan how many number, for example if I input 4 and the exponent is 2 then the calculation should be like this: 1² + 2² + 3² + 4². Getting the total sum, the output should be 30.

I tried searching for how to make a for loop program with exponent but only came up with how to get the sum of 1 value like if i input 4 and the exponent is 2, it only multiply the 4 by its exponent and get the sum of 16.

This is my code so far and I'm stuck:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int base = 0, exponent = 0;
    long result = 1;
    System.out.print("Enter #: ");
    base = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter exponent: ");
    exponent = in.nextInt();

    for (;exponent! = 0; --exponent){
       result *= base;
     }
     System.out.println("Answer = " + result);
 }
```

Thank you and hope you guys help me with this one.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int base = 0, exponent = 0;
    double result = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter #: ");
    base = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter exponent: ");
    exponent = in.nextInt();

    int count = 1;

    while(count<=base){
        result = result + Math.pow(count, exponent);
        System.out.println("PartialAmount = " + result);
        count++;
    }

    System.out.println("Answer = " + result);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is it. Thank you so much.. Im only half way a while ago and stuck on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Exponents extends ConsoleProgram {

  public void run(){
      for (int n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {

            println("2 to the power of " + n + " = " + raiseIntPower(n)); 

     } 

  }
private int raiseIntPower (int n){
   int total = 0;
   for( int n = 0; n <= 10; n++){
     total = Math.pow(2, n);

  } 

return total;
```

Comment: Thanks sir. But your code is a lot more complicated than i thought. I'm just beginning to use the java and I'm only learning about loops so far. But thanks it have the same result. And I'm going to use it for references someday. I really appreciate it sir, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

---

### By using math function

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOfExponents {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int base = 0, exponent = 0;
        long result = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter base value: ");
            base = in.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter exponent: ");
            exponent = in.nextInt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Illigal number entered");
            in.close();
            return;
        }
        String expression = "";
        for(int i=1; i<=base; i++){
            result += Math.pow(i, exponent);
            expression += " + "+String.join("^", Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(exponent));
        }
        System.out.println(expression.substring(3)+" = "+result);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

---

### without using any math functions

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOfExponents {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int base = 0, exponent = 0;
    long result = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter base value: ");
        base = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter exponent: ");
        exponent = in.nextInt();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Illigal number entered");
        in.close();
        return;
    }
    String expression = "";
    for(int i=1; i<=base; i++){
        long temp = 1;
        for(int j=0; j<exponent; j++){
            temp *= i;  
        }
        result += temp;
        expression += " + "+String.join("^", Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(exponent));
    }
    System.out.println(expression.substring(3)+" = "+result);
    in.close();
}

}
```